# if $\theta$ increases at a constant rate of 3 rads per min, at what rate is x increasing in units per min when x = 3 units?

Tags: calculus

[image: triangle:]

In triangle shown above, if $\theta$ increases at a constant rate of 3 radians per minute, at what rate is $x$ increasing in units per minute when $x$ equals $3$ units?

The answer is 12

Comment: Do you know how to set up related rates problems or implicit differentiation?

Comment: yes we are supposed to use related rates

Comment: i did $5cos(\theta)\theta'=x'$

Comment: Plug in what you know.  You know $\theta '$ is 3, and you should be able to find $\theta$ since it's a right triangle and you know two sides (5 and 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the constraint $$x = 5 \sin \theta, \to \frac{dx}{dt} = 5\cos \theta \frac{d\theta}{dt} = 15 \cos \theta = 15 \times \frac 4 5=12  \, unit/min $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\theta =\arcsin(3/5)$$

$$x'=5\cos(\arcsin(3/5))\cdot3$$

$$x'=12 \text{ units/min}$$